# Porting Java code to Android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, porting, face-recognition

I have [Java code for face recognition](http://darnok.org/programming/face-recognition/) which works fine. There is a problem however if I port the code into an Android application.

I have included the necessary jama and jmf which is required by the Java code into the Android app. The Android code compiles fine, but when I run the app it's force closed!

What might I be doing wrong here? What are the things that I need to keep in mind when I do the porting?

*By the way there is no GUI for the Java code.*

Comment: Android has its own API for video capture so why do you need to use JMF?

Comment: ok i really dont use video capture.

Comment: @DEKE: Post the error you get from LogCat. There's absolutely NO way we can help you without an idea what error is causing the FC, and on what line of code it is occurring.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error shown. All that is shown is this: ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.fr/.facerecongition }

Comment: If it's FCing, there has to be an exception somewhere. Can you post a good portion of the log directly after a crash?

Comment: Android Launch!
[2011-05-21 22:07:28 - FRAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-21 22:07:28 - FRAndroid] Performing com.android.fr.facerecongition activity launch
[2011-05-21 22:07:28 - FRAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'VD'
[2011-05-21 22:07:28 - FRAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-05-21 22:07:28 - FRAndroid] Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1)

Comment: [2011-05-21 22:07:32 - FRAndroid] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-05-21 22:07:32 - FRAndroid] Starting activity com.android.fr.facerecongition on device 
[2011-05-21 22:07:35 - FRAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.fr/.facerecongition }

Comment: This is the eclipse console log, people want to see the logcat log from 'adb logcat' in a terminal or from the logcat window of DDMS.  When you find that, you'll start getting buried in verbose messages from the garbage collector and everything else on the phone (there are some filters you can add once you know what you are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Porting your java code to Android will usually not work, you need to foloow the guidelines for creating an Android application.

You should start at the Android documentation for help.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at the [Android OpenCV project](http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/). In their CVCamera sample, they have a nice setup for doing real-time image processing for feature detection etc. I've previously modified it to support face detection using the OpenCV library.

If you want to use your own code instead, I suggest you strip out all the JNI/NDK interop code and substitute your own. At any rate, it's a nice starting point.